# fastText can train with a corpus bigger than RAM?

Tags: fasttext

I need to train a fastText model on a 400GB corpus. As I don't have a machine with 400GB of RAM I want to know if the fastText implementation ( for example, following this tutorial https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html ) supports corpus bigger than RAM, and which RAM requirements I would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for such models, the peak RAM requirement is a function of the size of the vocabulary of unique words, rather than the raw training material.

So, are there only 100k unique words in your 400GB? No problem, it'll only be reading a range at a time, & updating a small, stable amount of RAM. Are there 50M unique words? You'll need a lot of RAM.

Have you tried it to see what wold happen?

Comment: No, I need to test fasttext specirically. With other algorithms they failed with OOM.

Comment: If you have a 400GB file with your words, you could try it with the Facebook `fasttext` code to see if it works or how it fails. Or, simply survey the text to get an estimate of the number of unique words. When you say other algorithms failed with an OOM, if they're in the word2vec family, again, it's a matter of vocab-size more than corpus-size - and the reasons for a specific OOM could be specific parameter/data-handling choices that coudl be worked-around.